# Use table to do replacements

Tags: sql

Total and complete SQL rookie here, using general SQL I need to replace department numbers in a temp table identifying the new dept numbers.

Here is the full context:  We have year over year reports that show expenses by department.   Some (not all) of these departments have been eliminated for the upcoming year and consolidated into different departments.

For example, I have departments 1-10.  1-5 are not changing, but 6 & 7 will be department 7.  8, 9, & 10 will be 8 in the new year.  So I will have a table with columns 'old dept' and 'new dept' with values:
6,7
9,8
10,8
(I don't need 7,7 or 8,8)

I pull all department expenses into a temp table with 'Dept' being one of the columns.  When I first query the data for 2018 & 2019, the departments will be what they historically were (9 & 10 will show 9 & 10).  I need to cycle through each record and replace 9 with 8, and 10 with 8, etc etc etc.

I was told I could accomplish the same thing with a join, but I am not sure how this is done.

Sorry for the rambling mess; as you can see I still have not passed SQL 101.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more concrete?  Having the table and column names would be most helpful.  Also, if you think of this more as producing a _query_ that shows the modern department numbers instead of _updating a table_, I think it will be easier to use JOIN.

Comment: The robust, long term solution for this category of problem is called a [slowly changing dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) which is often part of a [data warehouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse).  You should think about asking whoever gave you this problem for expert assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a translations table, which you then join into every query that you need to report on:

```
create table translations
(old int,
 new int);

insert into translations values
(1,1)
,(2,2)
,(3,3)
,(4,4)
,(5,5)
,(6,7)
,(7,7)
,(8,8)
,(9,8)
,(10,8);

create table example_data
(dept int, revenue int);

insert into example_data values
(1,1000)
,(2,2000)
,(3,3000)
,(4,4000)
,(5,5000)
,(6,6000)
,(7,7000)
,(8,8000)
,(9,9000)
,(10,10000);

select new, sum(revenue)
from translations
inner join example_data on dept=old
group by new;
```